# .NET, C#, SQL Server: Invalid object name with CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am trying to execute a CREATE TABLE which results in the following SQL exception:

> Invalid object name 'UserLock'.

The statement looks like this:

```
USE [db]
GO

CREATE TABLE [db].[dbo].[UserLock] (
    [Login] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ExpirationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserLock] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ([Login] ASC)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The strange part is that I can run the query successfully inside the Microsoft SQL Management Studio with the same user but not within my .NET web application written in C#. I am not using any frameworks and I connect to the database with the provided classes out of System.Data.SqlClient. All other database queries work within the app. The database is Microsoft SQL Express 2005.

-- Edit ---

This is how my execution code looks like:

```
    string createString = "CREATE TABLE [" + catalog + "].[dbo].[UserLock]("
                        + "  [Login] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,"
                        + "  [ExpirationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,"
                        + "  CONSTRAINT [PK_UserLock] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED "
                        + "  ([Login] ASC)"
                        + "  WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]"
                        + ") ON [PRIMARY]";

    SqlCommand createCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
    createCommand.Connection = connection;
    createCommand.CommandText = createString;

    selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I catch the exception in another method. The SQL connection itself is beeing set up in antoher method, aswell. It's the standard `SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);`

Comment: How are you calling (using which method) SQL from .NET?

Comment: How are you executing the SQL in you C# program?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you are executing the above SQL but be aware that GO is not a SQL keyword, it is a command to tell SQL Management Studio to execute the current batch.  I.E you cannot use GO outside of SQL management studio.  Also i can't see how using GO would result in the above error.  It might be best if you post the entire c# code that fails as the error might be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely remove the following code:

`USE [db]
GO`

You have fully qualified the create table statement with [Database].[Schema].[ObjectName] so it will create the table in the correct database and schema anyway.

Also, you shouldn't use `GO` in C# as it is specific to the SQL Mgmt Studio and is used to separate batches of SQL statements.  If you really must use `GO` then take a look at Sql Server Management Object classes.

There is a nice [blog post from Jon Galloway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/07/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-2D00-the-easy-way.aspx) about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you rename the table name? Does it work then, could be a protected word.

Comment: String escaped with square brackets will not be parsed as a reserved keyword